# TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/activeandroid/ActiveAndroid.class

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Please let me know what exactly require here, I can see same source is running fine in Android Studio Emulators but in third party emulators like bluestacks I can see following errors.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/activeandroid/ActiveAndroid.class

Please check my gradle dependencies here.

```
dependencies {
apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
compile files('library/android-viewbadger.jar')
compile files('library/robobinding-0.8.1.jar')
compile files('library/activeandroid-3.1-SNAPSHOT.jar')
compile project(':Android-Validator')
```

//    compile files('library/java-rt-jar-stubs-1.5.0.jar')
}

```
dependencies {
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'){
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
compile 'com.f2prateek.progressbutton:progressbutton:2.1.0@aar'
compile files('library/afreechart-0.0.4.jar')
compile 'commons-io:commons-io:+'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.+'
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:16+'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4'
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.1'
compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE'
compile 'com.sun.codemodel:codemodel:2.4.1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.1'
compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.0'
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.2'
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
compile ('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1'){
    exclude module: 'stax'
    exclude module: 'stax-api'
    exclude module: 'xpp3'
}
compile files('library/pdfjet-5.75.jar')
compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
compile 'com.splunk:mint-android-sdk:5.2.1'
compile 'de.mindpipe.android:android-logging-log4j:1.0.3'
compile files('library/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.5.8-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

}

Comment: have you tried to clean your project ?

Comment: Yes, I tried clean option as well as Invalidate cache and restart, I am facing this problem only in third party emulator, Native emulators app is fine.

Answer (score 1):

This issue usually came when the same class is added in gradle twice.
Why you are using

```
compile files('library/activeandroid-3.1-SNAPSHOT.jar')
```

and

```
compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

This is the reason for this.Try adding it once only and then build the gradle and run

Comment: Thanks @Android Geek for pointing this, but by removing activeandroid-3.1-SNAPSHOT.jar from dependencies, cleaning cache and clean build, I can see Error:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded error. But In case If I use both activeandroid I can run app in emulator but not in BlueStacks. So I am little confuse how this is happening.